# Return value from a function callback in a for loop

Tags: javascript, reselect

I have the following for loop:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

let dirtyForm;

export const isFormDirty = createSelector(
    getForms,
    getState,
    (forms, state) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < forms.length; i += 1){
            dirtyForm = isDirty(forms[i])(state);
        }

        return dirtyForm;
    }
);
```

isDirty from takes a single form name from the forms array and checks if the form has been edited. The reason why I am looping through the form names is to find out if the form available on screen has been edited.

it works but is there a way not having to use the for loop at all in this case?

Comment: not sure why you need to declare it outside...

Comment: With the loop as you have written it, `dirtyForm` will always be the value of `isDirty` for the last form in the list. What are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: Also weird you overwrite the variable on each iteration.... It is aways going to be the last form....

Comment: Just return true as soon as you have one true value, and return false when it exit the loop normally. What is the implementation of `isDirty`? If you want to do it without a standard loop, I guess you could filter the dirty ones out instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last form's state will always override the others in your loop.

If you're trying to detect whether *any* one of the forms is dirty, you could use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
export const isFormDirty = createSelector(
    getForms,
    getState,
    (forms, state) => forms.some(form => isDirty(form)(state)) // Will return true if one of the forms are dirty, false if all forms are clean
);
```

---

Alternatively, as @Danmoreng suggested in the comments, you could keep the loop, and prevent overriding by adding OR'ing the dirtyForm flag with itself:

```
for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i += 1) {

    // Once true, further results will not be evaluated, so no overrides
    dirtyForm = dirtyForm || isDirty(forms[i])(state);
}
```

Or, as @Icepickle suggested in the comments, you could simply break the loop once you come across a dirty form:

```
for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i += 1) {

    // Exit the loop by returning true if a form is dirty
    // Might be wise to add a "return false;" outside the loop with this approach.
    if(isDirty(forms[i])(state)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Boom! Thank you

Comment: Just to point to the alternative with the loop instead of `Array.prototype.some()`: You would need to evaluate the boolean until it is true once. `dirtyForm = dirtyForm || isDirty(forms[i])(state)`.

Comment: @Danmoreng You would probably exit early from the loop instead, if one is dirty it seems like good enough to know that the form is dirty

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const isFormDirty = createSelector(
    getForms,
    getState,
    (forms, state) => forms.some(form => isDirty(form)(state))
);
```

EDIT: Removed map per excellent advice in the comments

Comment: No need for a snippet, it doesn't do anything anyhow. Also the map seems a bit overkill, as I `some` doesn't really iterate over all values, and your map would iterate over all first

Comment: If they are looking for only one true/false than it is a waste to check everyone when you get one hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.some()` to detect whether the array has a truthy conditional value.  Exits early and is very clean and perfomant.